# Visualizing most recent point by date in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, date

Does anyone know how to visualize in QGIS, in a group of points with an associated date, the point corresponding to the last date?

For example, a vector layer with 4 points:

| id | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joana | 2021-04-03 |
| 2 | Rita | 2020-12-05 |
| 3 | Nuno | 2021-01-12 |
| 4 | Mary | 2020-10-09 |

I just want to view the most recent date point, i.e. point 1.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a field called `Date` which is a `Date` type, then you can use a "Categorized" style with this expression:

```
to_datetime("Date") = maximum("Date")
```

this will be 1 for features at the maximum date value and zero otherwise. Hit "Classify" and disable display of the zero category. Style the one category however:

[image]

Note how `maximum("Date")` is a "DateTime" type so you have to convert your "Date" to a "DateTime" type or the comparison doesn't work because your date is a "Date" type. Or at least the data I made up was, I used the "Date" type in the attribute field.